# have a select statement with joins and unions and cant get it to work

Tags: mysql

So a mobile telephony question. Have an adjacency table listing all the source and target adjacencies. So the target cell can be an external/border cell or a normal cell. So first I want to check if the target is a normal cell and if not I want to load the list of external cells from the external cell table. 
So the tables are `c_adjacent_cell_4g`, the normal cell table is `c_ecell` and the target cell can be from the `c_ecell` table or from the `c_externaleutrancellfdd` table. Note the source cell will always be a normal cell and the target cell can be a normal cell or an external cell. So to my rather poor attempt at a select statement.

```
SELECT INT_ID, int_id 
FROM (
    SELECT adj.int_id, if(src.earfcnDl = tgt.earfcnDl, 'ADJS', 'ADJI') AS TYPE 
    FROM C_ADJACENT_CELL_4G adj 
    JOIN C_ECELL src ON (src.int_id = adj.src_cell_int_id) 
    JOIN C_ECELL tgt ON (tgt.int_id = adj.adj_cell_int_id) 
    LEFT JOIN C_EXTERNALEUTRANCELLFDD tgt ON (tgt.int_id = adj.adj_cell_int_id) 
    WHERE src.earfcndl IS NOT NULL AND tgt.earfcndl IS NOT NULL) DATA;
```

Is it possible I should be using a union statement rather than a left join. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you select `INT_ID` twice? And what's the point of the `TYPE` column in the subquery?

Comment: You're using the alias `tgt` twice. You need a different alias for `C_EXTERNALEUTRANCELLFDD`

Answer (score 1):

We could make use a `UNION ALL` set operator, to combine rows from `C_ECELL` and `C_EXTERNALEUTRANCELLFDD` into a single set, as an inline view, and then join to the combined set:

```
SELECT ...

  FROM C_ADJACENT_CELL_4G adj
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT 'i' AS src
              , intl.int_id
              , intl.earfcndl
           FROM C_ECELL int
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'e' AS src
              , extl.int_id
              , extl.earfcndl
           FROM C_EXTERNALEUTRANCELLFDD extl
       ) tgt
    ON tgt.int_id = ...
```

If the same value of `int_id` appears in both `intl` and `extl`, the join operation will match both rows.

---

But I would avoid the UNION ALL approach. And instead do outer joins to both of the target tables. And then do a check (in an expression in the SELECT list) to determine if we found a match in `C_ECELL`.  If not, we must have found a match in `C_EXTERNALEUTRANCELLFDD`.

Something along these lines:

```
SELECT adj.int_id     AS _adj__int_id
     , src.int_id     AS _src__int_id
     , tgt.int_id     AS _tgt__int_id
     , ext.int_id     AS _ext__int_id

     , src.earfcndl   AS _src__earfcndl
     , tgt.earfcndl   AS _tgt__earfcndl
     , ext.earfcndl   AS _ext__earfcndl

     , IF(adj.adj_cell_int_id = tgt.int_id, 'internal', 'external')

  FROM C_ADJACENT_CELL_4G adj

  JOIN C_ECELL src
    ON src.int_id = adj.src_cell_int_id

  LEFT
  JOIN C_ECELL tgt
    ON tgt.int_id = adj.adj_cell_int_id

  LEFT
  JOIN C_EXTERNALEUTRANCELLFDD ext
    ON ext.int_id = adj.adj_cell_int_id

 WHERE src.earfcndl IS NOT NULL
   AND ( tgt.earfcndl IS NOT NULL OR ext.earfcndl IS NOT NULL )
```

(The condition in the WHERE clause guarantees us that we found a matching row in either `tgt` or `ext`; if there wasn't a matching row in either, then `earfcndl` column from both outer joined tables would be NULL.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to join with a `UNION` of `C_ECELL` and `C_EXTERNALEUTRANCELLFDD`.

```
SELECT adj.int_id, if(src.earfcnDl = tgt.earfcnDl, 'ADJS', 'ADJI') AS TYPE 
FROM C_ADJACENT_CELL_4G adj 
JOIN C_ECELL src ON (src.int_id = adj.src_cell_int_id) 
JOIN (
    SELECT int_id, earfcnDl
    FROM C_ECELL
    WHERE earfcndl IS NOT NULL
    UNION
    SELECT int_id, earfcnDl
    FROM C_EXTERNALEUTRANCELLFDD
    WHERE earfcndl IS NOT NULL) AS tgt ON (tgt.int_id = adj.adj_cell_int_id) 
WHERE src.earfcndl IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Works a treat and provides exactly what I need. So very grateful. To answer your question about the use of two int_ids in the provided select statement, the second int_id is just a dummy value to replicate a second value I do use in the select statement which I pass into the method that executes the select statement. Most happy